# separate only specific columns into multiple across a table

Tags: r, dplyr, multiple-columns, tidyr

I have this small table called `table_8[1:2,]`:

```
structure(list(X1 = c("", ""), X2 = c("Wealth", "Ratio (75/25)"
), X3 = c("", "Gini"), X4 = c("Non-Land Wealth", "Ratio (75/25) Gini"
), X5 = c("Income", "Ratio (75/25)"), X6 = c("", "Gini"), X7 = c("Consumption", 
"Ratio (75/25) Gini")), row.names = 1:2, class = "data.frame")
```

looks like:

[image]

I need the second row of X4 and X7 to each be split into two columns so they look like X2 and X3.

I've tried:

```
table_8_n <- table_8[1:2,] |>
mutate(across(X4:X7, ~str_replace_all(.x, ") G", ")_G")))|>
separate_wider_delim(cols = c(X4,X7), names=LETTERS[1:2], names_sep = "",
                       delim="_", too_few = "align_start")
```

but it returns this error:

```
Error in `mutate()`:
ℹ In argument: `across(X4:X7, ~str_replace_all(.x, ") G", ")_G"))`.
Caused by error in `across()`:
! Can't compute column `X4`.
Caused by error in `stri_replace_all_regex()`:
! Incorrectly nested parentheses in regex pattern. (U_REGEX_MISMATCHED_PAREN, context=`) G`)
```

and I haven't been able to figure out what to put instead of "across".

Comment: Can you show your intended output?

Comment: This seems more like a data import issue that is easier to avoid than fix.  Can you open your data file in a text editor and copy-paste couple of lines to your question (as text, NOT as screenshots from e.g. Excel) , along with data import code (read.csv / read.table / read_csv / read_delim / .. )?

Comment: @LMc, The intended output would just be exactly as it is now except that both X4 and X7 would each be split into two columns that look like X2 and X3 with "Non-Land Wealth" for X4 and "Consumption" for X7 instead of "Wealth",

Comment: @margusl, I would much rather figure out how to do this within R, especially as I don't think the solution should be that complicated. All I want to do is replace any occurrences of ") " in the table with ")_", which would only affect columns X4 and X7 in row 2. Then the rest of the code should work.

Comment: Thanks for your comments, they helped inspire a new approach. I've posted the solution.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The issue is that in regular expressions, (a.k.a. regex), brackets have to be escaped (in other words, they have to have a backslash before them - or, in the case of R, two backslashes before them).

One that is done, your code works:

```
table_8 |> 
  mutate(across(X4:X7, ~str_replace_all(.x, "\\) G", "\\)_G"))) |>
  separate_wider_delim(cols = c(X4,X7), names=LETTERS[1:2], names_sep = "",
                       delim="_", too_few = "align_start") |>
  mutate(across(everything(), ~ ifelse(is.na(.), "", .))) # I added this so it appears as it should in your screenshot, without NAs in the empty cells
```

Output:

```
# A tibble: 2 × 9
  X1    X2            X3     X4A             X4B    X5         X6    X7A   X7B  
  <chr> <chr>         <chr>  <chr>           <chr>  <chr>      <chr> <chr> <chr>
1 ""    Wealth        ""     Non-Land Wealth ""     Income     ""    Cons… ""   
2 ""    Ratio (75/25) "Gini" Ratio (75/25)   "Gini" Ratio (75… "Gin… Rati… "Gin…
```

Answer (score 0):

```
table_8_n <- data.frame(lapply(table_8[1:2,], function(x) {
                      gsub(") ",")_",x)  
})) |>
  separate_wider_delim(cols = c(X4,X7), names=LETTERS[1:2], names_sep = "",
                       delim="_", too_few = "align_start")
```

[image]